# Regarding controlling the font/size of character in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, rhel, fontconfig

At present, I am using the linux system with the following version,

```
bash-4.2$ lsb_release -idrc
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseWorkstation
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.9 (Maipo)
Release:    7.9
Codename:   Maipo
```

the terminal information is

```
bash-4.2$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Are there any systematic ways to change the font/size for the character in the terminal? Currently, I only use ctrl++ to zoom in, which is pretty ad-hoc, and I cannot select the font style either.

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: `$TERM` and xterm-256color is a generic type. What does `cat /proc/$PPID/comm` say? Or `ps -o cmd= -p $PPID` - (if result from either is `some-term`, then you can also do `some-term --version`), or live on the edge and say `$(which $(ps -o 'cmd=' -p $PPID)) --version`